Launching https on Tomcat Port 8443 - requires the APR/native library which is not available
I need advice on https.
Below is the configuration of the server.xml file
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
               <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
                  <SSLHostConfig>               
                      <Certificate 
                      certificateKeyFile="conf/privateKey.pem"
                      certificateFile="conf/certificateCA.crt"
                      certificateChainFile="conf/certificate.crt"
                      type="RSA" />
                  </SSLHostConfig>

However, this configuration does not run the mi server on port 8443.
No listening on port 8443.
It only works on port 8080.
The following message appears in the Tomcat logs:
15-Jul-2024 13:53:17.390 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] 15-Jul-2024 13:53:17.406 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol-8443]] org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: The configured protocol [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] requires the APR/native library which is not available at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal

How do I fix this?

You're correct. As far as I can see it should run. Perhaps an older instance of TC is running without listening to port 8443. Also, check that the Connector for 8433 is not commented out in server.xml - it is in the default TC install. What about adding the TC startup logs so we can see which connectors start and if there are any issues?

Thank you for your answer :).
Which log file exactly should I check/share?
What strings to look for?

Whatever goes to stdout, stderror, ie the console where you start TC. Have a ferret around the newest updated files in %TOMCAT_HOME%/logs.

This is probably the reason.
How to fix it ?
15-Jul-2024 13:53:17.390 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
15-Jul-2024 13:53:17.406 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol-8443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: The configured protocol [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] requires the APR/native library which is not available
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal...

"This is probably the reason". Which is probably the reason? Why? logs?

requires the APR/native library which is not available at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal..

Add that error to the question and I will answer. Which version of TC & which OS you using?

TC 9.0.78 and OS WIN SERVER 2022. I downloaded Apache Tomcat Native Library.
But I don't know how to implement it?
This is an OpenSSL file and libraries

Launching https on Tomcat Port 8443 does not require the APR/native library. Using that library is optional. You can choose not to use it - and use the Java JSSE implementation instead. It's up to you - and how you set up your <Connector>. See the documentation.

In your case it's only "required" because you have specified it in your <Connector>: protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol".

The fix on TC9 and Windows is to install the APR in accordance with this.
Download the zipped TCL for Windows here.
Unzip it.
Copy the file at tomcat-native-1.3.0-openssl-3.0.13-win32-bin.zip\bin\x64\tcnative-1.dll into the java bin folder used by Tomcat, ie %JRE_HOME%/bin. You can also drop it in C:\Windows\System32 if you can't locate the java bin location.
Start Tomcat. You should see the following in the logs and HTTPS being served on port 8443.
 OpenSSL successfully initialized


Hi John, thank you for your support and tips. After adding the dll, it works correct.
Logabbr below:

Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.3.0] using APR version [1.7.4].
APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024]
*coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.configureUpgradeProtocol The ["https-openssl-apr-8443"] connector has been configured to support negotiation to [h2] via ALPN
*coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-openssl-apr-8443"]


I have another question about the SSL attribute:
'''
SSLVerifyClient="optional" SSLProtocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2 or sslProtocol="TLS"
'''
After adding this attribute, the TC server does not start.
Do I need this attribute?
Because there are config files for https with this attribute circulating on the Internet.

First, can you please accept and upvote my answer. You don't need the attribute. However, you probably want to block TLS1 and possibly TLS1.1 because they are hackable. Because you are using APR try SSLProtocol="-TLSv1-TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2+TLS1.3"
